# How to execute cypher query within a CASE WHEN THEN clause in Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a use case where I am trying to optimize my Neo4j db calls and code by using the RETURN CASE WHEN THEN clauses in Cypher to run different queries depending on the WHEN result. This is my example:

```
MATCH (n {email: 'abc123@abc.com'}) 
RETURN  
CASE WHEN n.category='Owner' THEN  MATCH '(n)-[r:OWNS]->(m)'  
WHEN n.category='Dealer' THEN MATCH (n)-[r:SUPPLY_PARTS_FOR]->(m) 
WHEN n.category='Mechanic' THEN MATCH (n)-[r:SERVICE]-(m) END 
AS result;
```

I am not sure this is legal but this is what I want to achieve. I am getting syntax errors like  Invalid input '>'. How can I achieve this in the best manner?
EDIT for possible APOC solution:
This was my plan before discovering the limitation of FOREACH...

```
MATCH (user:Person {email:{paramEmail}})
FOREACH (_ IN case when 'Owner' = {paramCategory} then [1] else [] end|
SET user:Owner, user += queryObj 
WITH user, {paramVehicles} AS coll
UNWIND coll AS vehicle
MATCH(v:Vehicles {name:vehicle}) 
CREATE UNIQUE (user)-[r:OWNS {since: timestamp()}]->(v)
SET r += paramVehicleProps 
)
FOREACH (_ IN case when 'Mechanic' = {Category} then [1] else [] end|
SET user:Owner, user += queryObj 
WITH user, {paramVehicles} AS coll
….
)
FOREACH (_ IN case when 'Dealer' = {paramCategory} then [1] else [] end|
SET user:Owner, user += queryObj 
WITH user, {paramVehicles} AS coll
…...

)
RETURN user,
CASE {paramCategory}

WHEN 'Owner' THEN [(n)-[r:OWNS]->(m) | m and r]
 WHEN 'Dealer' THEN [(n)-[r:SUPPLY_PARTS_FOR]->(m) | m] 
WHEN 'Mechanic' THEN [(n)-[r:SERVICE]-(m) | m]
 END AS result`,{
 paramQueryObj: queryObj,
 paramVehicles: makeVehicleArray,
 paramVehicleProps: vehiclePropsArray,
 paramSalesAgent: dealerSalesAgentObjarray,
 paramWarehouseAgent: dealerWarehouseAgentObjarray
}).....
```

does anyone know to convert this using apoc.do.when()? note I need 'm' and 'r' in the first THEN.

Answer (score 6):

You should still use a label in your first match, otherwise you get a full database scan and not a index lookup by email!!

for your query you can use pattern comprehensions:

```
MATCH (n:Person {email: 'abc123@abc.com'}) 
RETURN  
CASE n.category 
WHEN 'Owner'    THEN  [(n)-[r:OWNS]->(m) | m]
WHEN 'Dealer'   THEN [(n)-[r:SUPPLY_PARTS_FOR]->(m) | m] 
WHEN 'Mechanic' THEN [(n)-[r:SERVICE]-(m) | m] END 
AS result;
```

Comment: Are there limits on type of queries I can use in the then block? I would like to UNWIND parameters and CREATE nodes etc within the then block....Also, is there a deeper documentation on this than the developers doc?

Comment: You can't use clauses (such as UNWIND and CREATE etc) within CASE statements. Michael's approach works because pattern comprehensions (extracting out a list of results from a pattern) are expressions. Here's an answer on our community site which provides options for [conditional cypher execution](https://community.neo4j.com/t/how-to-check-if-else-in-query/1533/2).

Comment: Ok...so I was planning to use a combination of FOREACH and CASE WHEN but @InverseFalcon exploded that idea with the fact that FOREACH doesn't allow MATCH,WITH, etc. So now the suggestion is apoc.do.when()...I have edited the question to show the my intent ...how do I use apoc.do.when to achieve this.

Comment: Still really useful in 2020, neo4j 3.5.

Comment: If I want to return union of OWNS and SUPPLY_PARTS_FOR in both cases Owner and Dealer, is it possible? getting syntax error, with this query: CASE n.category 
WHEN 'Owner'    THEN  [(n)-[r:OWNS|:SUPPLY_PARTS_FOR]->(m) | m]
WHEN 'Dealer'   THEN [(n)-[r:OWNS|:SUPPLY_PARTS_FOR]->(m) | m]

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use apoc.do.case: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/overview/apoc.do/apoc.do.case/

```
CALL apoc.do.case([
  false,
  'CREATE (a:Node{name:"A"}) RETURN a AS node',
  true,
  'CREATE (b:Node{name:"B"}) RETURN b AS node'
  ],
  'CREATE (c:Node{name:"C"}) RETURN c AS node',{})
YIELD value
RETURN value.node AS node;
```